# Protocol inside for loop for inside Obj C, just like interface inside for loop inside Java

Tags: java, objective-c, interface, protocols

I am trying to do something similar in Objective C, I have this Java code here:

```
public interface Subscriber {
    Object register();
    void unregister();
}

public void registerDefaultSubscribers() {
    mDefaultEventSubscribers.clear;
    mDefaultEventSubscribers.addAll(createDefaultSubscribers());
    for (Subscriber subscriber : mDefaultEventSubscribers)
        registerSubscriber(subscriber);
}
```

This is how I was thinking about doing it in Objective-C

```
@protocol Subscriber <NSObject>

- (NSObject *)register;
- (void)unregister;

@end

# pragma registerSubscribers

- (void)registerDefaultSubscribers {
    [_defaultNotificationSubscribers removeAllObjects];
    [_defaultNotificationSubscribers addObjectsFromArray:[self createDefaultSubscribers]];
    for (id<CLNotificationSubscriber> subscriber in _defaultNotificationSubscribers) {
        [self registerSubscriber:subscriber];
    }
}
```

Does this look correct, any issues with the way I am doing this in Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.

```
- (NSObject *)register;
```

Objective-C types dynamically. Therefore, if you do not have a common base class for all return values, you use `id` instead of `NSObject`. `NSObject` is one possible base class, not the base class of all objects.

```
- (id)register;
```

Maybe you want to add a protocol to the type.

B.

```
(void)registerDefaultSubscribers 
{
  [_defaultNotificationSubscribers removeAllObjects];
  [_defaultNotificationSubscribers addObjectsFromArray:[self createDefaultSubscribers]];
  …
}
```

Assuming that `_defaultNotificationSubscribers` is a (mutable) array, I do not know, why you change the existing instance instead of creating a new one. Why don't you use setters and getters to enable KVO?

Beside this, "create" sounds like a method that does a creation and returns a success flag. I would call it `-defaultSubscribers`. Whether they are created is an implementation detail:

```
(void)registerDefaultSubscribers 
{
  self.defaultNotificationSubscribers = [self defaultSubscribers];
  …
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a registry of classes that will act as observers on the NSNotificationCenter. Thanks for explaining id and NSObject! Would this be the right way to do this?

Comment: Also is it possible to have something like this in Objective C. `HashMap<Object, Subscriber>`? I am thinking about using a `NSMapTable`.

Comment: I really do not know, why you want to have a registry of observers on the notification center, because the notification center already cares about observers. What is the idea behind that? This is not re-inventing the wheel, but a machine to make wheels round!? They are already.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. 1. Cocoa collections are grouped "what they are", not "how they are implemented". In most cases `NSDictionary` is the right way to go. `NSMapTable` is for memory management purpose and some other details. Forget about it at this point. 2. You do not type collections in source code, because Objective-C is dynamically typed. However, there is support for something like that, but this is to explain modern programming techniques to static typing Swift. If you do not use Swift, because you do not want to travel to the early 70's, simply forget about it, too.

Comment: Maybe it feels "safer" to you (coming from Java) to have static typing. It is a feeling, nothing else.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a registry to hold subscribers for a few reasons:

1.) I didn't want to instantiate the subscribers in a view but hold them somewhere else, and add them as observers to the NSNotificationCenter. This keeps views decoupled from Notifications.

2.) This registry is created at application startup, then de allocated on application termination.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things about NSMapTable, NSDictionary and HashMap

Comment: Simply use a Cocoa model technology like Core Data to store Subscribers. They might be observers or not. This is an implementation detail. You finde the way from view to controller via the action-target paradigm.

Comment: Ok again thanks for explaining this!! I'm an Android developer initially.